# Telemetry mixer logs

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I deploy istio 1.2.5 on a K8s cluster.

According to documentation https://istio.io/faq/mixer/  in rules section:

```
kubectl get rules --all-namespaces
```

You will get the list. In my cluster I got `No resources found`

But if I use:

```
kubectl get rules.config.istio.io -n istio-system
```

I got the list:

```
NAME                      AGE
kubeattrgenrulerule       5h
promhttp                  5h
promtcp                   5h
promtcpconnectionclosed   5h
promtcpconnectionopen     5h
stdio                     5h
stdiotcp                  5h
```

Someone know the difference?

Also if I try:

```
kubectl -n istio-system logs -f istio-telemetry-7df96d454b-4kxs9 -c mixer
```

I didn't got the log of request in the log ( I found it work in another cluster). Do you know why?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue on GKE but all works correctly. Your cluster is in cloud on baremetal? Could you provide output of `kubectl get pod -n istio-system -owide` to check if all required pods are in `Running` state. How did you install istio? Did you try the newest istio 1.3.0?

Comment: Hi,I now working in 1.3 . this is working: kubectl get rules.config.istio.io -n istio-system and not kubectl get rules -n istio-system. but the main issue is why when i tried to logs the mixer in telemetry i didn't see the request in the log.

Comment: As I mentioned before, could you provide more information. Your cluster is in cloud on baremetal? Could you provide output of `kubectl get pod -n istio-system -owide` to check if all required pods are in Running state. How did you install istio?

Comment: Baremetal cluster . all pods of istio are running. install istio with helm from github.

Comment: I have tried this on GKE, Minikube and Kubeadm. Everywhere it works as it should. Did you try to use helm installation steps from `Istio` site: https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/helm/ ? You mentioned that "I found it work in another cluster", maybe you have some specific configuration on this cluster? You have to add more details about your environment. Steps how you created cluster, steps with helm installation (e.g. github link)

Comment: I deployed the same helm chart on both clusters. https://github.com/istio/istio/releases/tag/1.3.0 - zip and inside you have the helm chart . i took all the default config. you try kubectl -n istio-system logs -f istio-telemetry <pod name>  -c mixer and got the requests logs?

Comment: Your steps was
`$ wget https://github.com/istio/istio/releases/download/1.3.0/istio-1.3.0-win.zip` unzip file, `$ kubectl create ns istio-system` and `$ helm template install/kubernetes/helm/istio-init --name istio-init --namespace istio-system | kubectl apply -f -` and then, what was your steps? `$ helm template install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system | kubectl apply -f -` ?
Could you provide output of `kubectl describe pod <your_telemetry_pod> -n istio-system`. Yes I am receiving mixer logs.

Comment: Also check output of `kubectl api-resources | grep rules` if "APIGROUP" config.istio.io have "NAME" rules.

Comment: When I run :kubectl logs -f  istio-telemetry-6dc458ff7-468dv  -n istio-system -c mixer I got in the log : something like this :gc 1537 @183375.442s 0%: 0.033+13+0.009 ms clock, 0.20+0/18/63+0.054 ms cpu, 39->39->34 MB, 69 MB goal, 6 P
scvg1222: 0 MB released
scvg1222: inuse: 46, idle: 12, sys: 58, released: 10, consumed: 48 (MB)
GC forced

Comment: I should get something like: {"level":"info","time":"2019-09-18T10:59:28.071530Z","instance":"accesslog.instance.istio-system","apiClaims":"","apiKey":"","clientTraceId":"","connection_security_policy":"none","destinationApp":"telemetry","destinationIp":"10.5.108.34",....} this is in the good env

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue on both versions `Istio 1.2.5` and `Istio 1.3.0` and environments like `GKE`, `Minikube` and `Kubeadm`.
I have tried to install it manually and using `HELM`. Each time everything worked as should.

Based on the information  you have provided: **I found it work in another cluster** and you are using bare metal I would guess that this cluster have some specific configuration or some of the `kubernetes/Istio` objects have Insufficient resources.

```
$ kubectl describe node [node-name]
```

Please keep in mind that you might install [Istio Configuration Profile](https://istio.io/docs/setup/additional-setup/config-profiles/) which requested too many resources. Each profile contain different amount of resources based on each object (citadel, egress, galley, pilot, telemetry, etc). For example if you will check [Istio Docs](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/performance-and-scalability/)

- The Envoy proxy uses 0.6 vCPU and 50 MB memory per 1000 requests per second going through the proxy.
- The istio-telemetry service uses 0.6 vCPU per 1000 mesh-wide requests per second.
- Pilot uses 1 vCPU and 1.5 GB of memory.

Comment: Hi , it also work in another envs. So what can be a problem specific to this env with istio config ?

Comment: It might depends from many factors. However as it was run on BareMetal i would guess that there was not enough resources to run all required `Jobs / Pods`. Another case could be network settings.
@erang If my answer was helpful please upvote/accept it.